# How to check if a Java class contains JUnit4 tests?

Tags: java, reflection, junit, junit4

I have a Java class.  How can I check if the class contains methods that are JUnit4 tests?  Do I have to do an iteration on all methods using reflection, or does JUnit4 supply such a check?

**Edit:**

since comments cannot contain code, I placed my code based on the answer here:

```
private static boolean containsUnitTests(Class<?> clazz) 
{
        List<FrameworkMethod> methods= new TestClass(clazz).getAnnotatedMethods(Test.class);
        for (FrameworkMethod eachTestMethod : methods)
        {
            List<Throwable> errors = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
            eachTestMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(false, errors);
            if (errors.isEmpty()) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw ExceptionUtils.toUncheked(errors.get(0));
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use built-in JUnit 4 class **org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod** to check methods.

```
/**
 * Get all 'Public', 'Void' , non-static and no-argument methods 
 * in given Class.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 * @return Validate methods list
 */
static List<Method> getValidatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(Class clazz) {

    List<Method> result = new ArrayList<Method>();

    List<FrameworkMethod> methods= new TestClass(clazz).getAnnotatedMethods(Test.class);

    for (FrameworkMethod eachTestMethod : methods){
        List<Throwable> errors = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
        eachTestMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(false, errors);
        if (errors.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(eachTestMethod.getMethod());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! see how I used it in the question body.

Comment: @ohadshai: A logic problem on 'if (errors.isEmpty()) {return true;}'. What is following a method fails the validation? You may fix it easily:)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your question can be reformulated as *"How can I check if the class contains methods with `org.junit.Test` annotation?"*, then use [`Method#isAnnotationPresent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#isAnnotationPresent%28java.lang.Class%29). Here's a kickoff example:

```
for (Method method : Foo.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(org.junit.Test.class)) {
        System.out.println("Method " + method + " has junit @Test annotation.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JUnit is commonly configured using either an annotation based approach or by extending TestCase. In the latter case I would use reflection to look for implemented interfaces (`object.getClass().getInterfaces()`). In the former case I would iterate all methods looking for @Test annotations, e.g.,

```
Object object; // The object to examine
for (Method method : object.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
    Annotation a = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
    if (a != null) {
        // found JUnit test
    }
}
```